# Do I need iml, iws ipr files in my Eclipse Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javafx

I've been given a codebase which has iml, iws,ipr files and some other files which I don't recognise. I can run the program when I import the source folder but not sure if I need these files, can I ignore them? I think they are IDEA root files, do I need them? I'm new to programming and don't understand if I need to import the root files to code or just the source files when programming. Any sources on learning information about building would also be helpful.

Comment: You don't need them, and they shouldn't generally be checked into source control.

Comment: So do I ignore the root directory completely and just import the source files?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need these files if you are using Eclipse. These are IntelliJ IDEA project files, see also [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839).

Comment: So do I ignore the root directory completely and just import the source files?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the root directory. Normally you import the project root directory, not just the `src` subdirectories.

Comment: This is where I'm confused, I've been given this codebase with 2 folders, one with the name of the project (guessing its called project folder not root) which has a bunch of iml files and a src folder with 2 java files and  then theres this other folder also called src which has a  bunch of java and png files, because I'm on eclipse I don't know how to import it with these iml files etc so I've just imported the big src folder and the code runs but I don't know if I need the things in the project folder. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: It would depend on the project. Other folders may have additional libraries and resources needed for the project, but it it works for you, you should be fine with just the src folder.

Comment: So how would you recommend importing a project into eclipse which has been exported from IDEA, would you use something else to build?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has File | [Export Project to Eclipse](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exporting-an-intellij-idea-project-to-eclipse.html) option. Then you just open the project file in Eclipse.